# CoreData (storing new object) in AppDelegate = SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I've intented to make a simple function in AppDelegate to store some data in database (CoreData) which would be called from various `ViewController` classes connected do `AppDelegate`. This is the body of this function:

```
- (void) setSetting:(NSString *)setting :(NSString *)value {    
    NSManagedObject* newSetting = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [newSetting setValue:value forKey:setting];
    NSError* error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

But calling this function (even from AppDelegate itself) returns SIGABRT on line with `setValue`

But when I implement the function in `ViewController` class (replacing `self.` with proper connection to `AppDelegate` of course) - it works **fine**.

I don't get it and I would really appreciate some help in creating flexible function in `AppDelegate` to save the data in database.

Comment: is your entity really called "EntityName"?

Comment: Do you have a `setting` property in the app delegate?

Comment: @TechZen: No, I don't have a setting in app delegate since it's a local function variable

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit like the `key` part is not an `NSString` or the `value` part is not the correct data type. Please check, and perhaps make the order of the arguments in your function the same as in the `setValue:forKey` method to avoid confusion.

Also, according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObject), an exception will be raised if the `key` is not defined in the model - so double-check your key strings.

BTW, if this is your error it is a good idea to move away from KVC and create your own `NSManagedObject` subclasses instead as a habit - makes life much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it didn't solve the problem. key and value are NSString as well entity properties. And there is no exception visible (or I don't know how to view them). There is only SIGABRT with no bold comments in console :/

Comment: Logic dictates, that something must be different in the function from when you call it from another controller. It could be that your managed object model is not properly initialized; that your `managedObjectContext` is nil; and such things. `NSLog` all the variables in question, and you should find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that this line:

```
NSManagedObject* newSetting = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

… returns a nil object either because the entity name is incorrect or because the managedObjectContext is itself nil or otherwise invalid.

Since the problem only occurs in the app delegate, I would first suspect some issue with `self.managedObjectContext`.